# How to read an integer from a string in ASP (VB)

Tags: vbscript

I have some picture named like this . (like "2.jpeg", "1234.gif" etc.)
how can I get the integer from the string?

I mean, is there something like the C function:

```
sscanf(myString,"%d", myInteger);
```

thanks

Alessandro

Comment: Which language are you using? Visual Basic or Visual Basic .NET? Please tag your question as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the non-numeric portion and then call `TryParse`.

```
Dim numericPortion As String
Dim result As Integer

numericPortion = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf('.'))
If (Not Int32.TryParse(numericPortion, ByRef result)) Then
    ''// Handle Error
Else
    ''// Use Result
End If
```